# Laravel Carbon - Calculate time between database entries

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to calculate de difference between two datetimes.

I have two Models, `tasks` and `task_interactions`, they are related like this: `tasks` has many `task_interactions`, and `task_interactions` belongs to `tasks`.

The user can change the status of a task to one of these: "In progress", "Paused" and Finished. The user change the status several times between "In Progress" and "Paused", but once it's finished, the user cannot change the task status anymore.

All interactions are saved in the `task_interactions` table, with `created_by` as user_id and `created_at` as the datetime. the table has these columns: `id ; task_id ; status ; comments ; created_by ; created_at`.

Here's na exemple for task id = 1:

```
# id, task_id, status, comments, created_by, created_at
144, 1, In Progress, , 1, 2017-11-14 09:42:20
145, 1, Paused, , 1, 2017-11-14 09:45:53
146, 1, In Progress, , 1, 2017-11-14 09:46:57
147, 1, Paused, , 1, 2017-11-14 09:49:57
148, 1, In Progress, , 1, 2017-11-14 10:00:10
149, 1, Paused, , 1, 2017-11-14 10:06:25
150, 1, In Progress, , 1, 2017-11-14 10:07:26
151, 1, Paused, , 1, 2017-11-14 10:08:11
153, 1, Paused, , 1, 2017-11-14 11:27:04
154, 1, In Progress, , 1, 2017-11-14 11:27:21
155, 1, Paused, , 1, 2017-11-14 11:57:38
```

The thing is, for me to have the total time spent in one task, i have to determine the time between `In Progress` and `Paused`. The time between `Paused` and `In Progress` is not relevant.

I am strugling with this. Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Just one more thing, i am not very experienced, so pardon if my questions sound a bit dummer, I believe that i should do a `@foreach` loop through all task_interactions where task_id = X, and thats all i know.

As asked, here's the data i am passing for the view:

```
public function mytasks()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $mytasks = Task::where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->where('status','!=','Finished')->get(); 
        $mytaskscount = Task::where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->count();
        $tasksinprogress = Task::where('status','=','In Progress')->where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->get();
        $tasksinprogresscount = Task::where('status','=','In Progress')->where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->count();
        $taskspaused = Task::where('status','=','Paused')->where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->get();
        $taskspausedcount = Task::where('status','=','Paused')->where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->count();
        $tasksfinished = Task::where('status','=','Finished')->where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->get();
        $tasksfinishedcount = Task::where('status','=','Finished')->where('assigned_to','=', Auth::id())->count();
        $tasktypes = Tasktype::all();
        $chapters = Chapter::all();

        return view('pages.tasks_my', compact('mytasks','tasktypes','chapters','tasksinprogress','taskspaused','tasksfinished','mytaskscount','tasksinprogresscount','taskspausedcount','tasksfinishedcount'));
    }
```

And one more thing, what i know so far

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
    @foreach ($task->interactions as $interactions)
{{ In here, every time my loop returns a status = "In progress" i should mark that time, and if that the next loop returns a "Paused", i should count the difference between these two. And sum all other equal cases in the loop. }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I realy have no idea on how to do that

Comment: can you push your controller?

Comment: i would also like to know answer to this question

Comment: do you personally in charge of letting db query to handle this? iterating the result by php is what comes in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This is strict Mysql, but should do the trick.
You can call this in laravel directly using raw sql instruction, or you should probably rework this into Laravel code.

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(
    sum( 
        timediff(
            if(task_end.created_at is null, 
               NOW(), 
               task_end.created_at), 
            task_start.created_at)))
from task_interactions task_start
left join task_interactions task_end
    ON task_end.task_id = task_start.task_id
    AND task_end.status IN ('Pause', 'Finished')
    AND task_end.created_at = (
        SELECT min(created_at)
        FROM task_interactions
        WHERE status = task_end.status
        AND created_at >= task_start.created_at
    )
WHERE task_start.task_id = 1
AND task_start.status = 'In Progress'
```

Comment: This is the main reason why I love Laravel... the vanilla code of PHP and SQL are so ugly and hard to read... It would be great if you could take some time and translate that to Laravel Eloquent

Comment: What is so difficult to read then?
This is basic SQL...

You take all your task_interactions whet a status 'In Progress'; I called them task_start; then I do a left join to other tasks with the same task_id (and I alias that task_end); for that join I only want tasks that are Paused or Finished.  Moreover - I want the first task in that end...

Laravel is good, but it'll be still this complicated if you want this using Eloquent.  Laravel is a great tool, but you still need to know what you're doing...

Comment: It is too much code, I know it can be done with laravel and less code!

Comment: well - if you want to put that load on the database, your laravel logic will be equally "difficult".  The alternative is that you loop through your records in laravel, and go from there...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, jus had to change the status_id for status. I was hopping for something more Eloquent. Now i just have to figure how to implement this in the model.

Comment: Sorry about that - I tested it with a table I set up of my own, and that was using status_id, so I had to update the query to reflect your entities and attributes before posting - I must have missed that one ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to add that when the last start event is not followed by a paused of finished event, I calculate duration for that final step up until NOW(), because I believe that means the task is currently being worked on :-)  If that's not your use case, you may need to alter that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend David's answer. If you are not comfortable doing it using MySQL. You may have to do it like this:

Calculate difference between first time a task was started & when it was paused:

```
$start = Carbon::parse($startTask->created_at);
$pause = Carbon::parse($endTask->created_at);

$diffInSeconds = $pause->diffInSeconds($start)
```

This should give you the total difference in seconds as to when a tasks was started & then paused. Now you have to repeat this approach for when again a task was started & then paused.

Comment: This might sound a bit odd, i understand your approach but i have no idea on how to put this inside a foreach loop. I am not very experienced , usualy what i do is to filter the data i need in the controller and then do the processing of that information in my view. I know its wrong

Comment: Its quite easy as you need to get all paused & starting entries for a task as array. Then you simply parse start entries for a task.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot